# STL random_shuffle generates highly correlated sequences

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Notice the accepted answer pointed out the problem lies in reseeding. Reseeding is not the reason. Tests without reseeding yielded high correlations before posting. See Note1.

I generated 1,000,000 uniform random numbers in R, sorted the sequence, and called `std::random_shuffle()` to permute a copy of this sequence 100 times. The 100 permuted sequences turned out extremely correlated. However, if I do not sort the uniform numbers in the first place, the 100 permuted sequences are more or less uncorrelated. Below are the code.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector testRandomShuffle(IntegerVector x, int rd) // rd is the seed
{
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end()); // copy
  std::srand(rd); // seeding
  std::random_shuffle(y.begin(), y.end());
  return y;
}


/***R
v = runif(1000000)
vSorted = sort(v)
sqc = 1L : length(v) # indexes
rd = sample.int(length(v), 100) # random seeds


# Compute correlation matrices
corMatForUnsorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  v[testRandomShuffle(sqc, x)])))
corMatForSorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  vSorted[testRandomShuffle(sqc, x)])))


# plot histograms
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) 
hist(corMatForUnsorted[abs(corMatForUnsorted) < 1], breaks = 200, xlab = 
  "Correlation for unsorted")
hist(corMatForSorted[abs(corMatForSorted) < 1], breaks = 200, xlab = 
  "Correlation for sorted")
*/
```

[image]

Did I do something very wrong? I simply expect shuffling sorted and unsorted sequences yields more or less the same distributions of correlations. How small should those correlations be is another story. The same experiment with R's native function `sample.int()` for permutation yields low correlations in both scenarios.

Thank you!

Note1: the problem is that I am on Windows using Rtools 3.4 that comes with g++ 4.9.3. The shuffle function in this version of C++ library works incorrectly.

Note2: confirmed that `Rcpp::sample()` works in multithreading. A small test case:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
# include <RcppParallel.h>
# include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


struct testSampleInPara: public RcppParallel::Worker
{
  IntegerVector tmp;
  List rst;


  void operator() (std::size_t st, std::size_t end)
  {
    if(st == 0)
    {
      // is tmp / rst a copy or a reference ?
      std::cout << std::to_string((std::size_t)&tmp[0]) + "\n";
      IntegerVector rst0 = Rcpp::sample(tmp, 5);
      rst[0] = rst0; // assume rst not a copy
    }
    else // if(st == 1)
    {
      std::cout << std::to_string((std::size_t)&tmp[0]) + "\n";
      IntegerVector rst1 = Rcpp::sample(tmp, 10);
      rst[1] = rst1;
    }
  }


  testSampleInPara(IntegerVector tmp, List rst):
    tmp(tmp), rst(rst)
  {
    RcppParallel::parallelFor(0, 2, *this);
  }
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
List testIfSampleCopy(IntegerVector tmp)
{
  List rst(2);
  testSampleInPara(tmp, rst);
  return rst;
}

/***R
testIfSampleCopy(1L : 10L)
# printout:
# 356036792
# 356036792
# [[1]]
# [1] 10  5  9  7  8
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 10  3  7  6  2  1  8  4  9  5
*/
```

My experience with `Rcpp` containers is bad regarding performance in multithreading. I usually create pointers or array of pointers to the beginning elements of `Rcpp` containers, share these pointers and the containers' sizes among threads. Notice `Rcpp::sample()` takes and returns `Rcpp` containers.

Note3: By reading `Rcpp` source code, the best solution is to program a customized `sample()` in native C++. The central component of `Rcpp::sample()` is `unif_rand()`. Integrate `unif_rand()` in the modern version of Fisher–Yates Shuffle. Problem solved.

Note4: Using `unif_rand()` in a multithreaded environment substantially slows down the speed of threads. I do not have time to read the documentation as Dirk Eddelbuettel suggested, but I guess R's source synchronizes `unif_rand()` someway invisible to us, like `malloc()` in `C`. The ultimate solution is to include `// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]` and play with `std::random`.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle(&y[0], &*y.end());` This looks like UB to me.

Comment: @tkausl I'm not actually sure. It's sometimes valid to dereference something invalid if you immediately take its address.

Comment: I think something is conceptually not right with your seeding (apart from using `rand()` and `srand()`), but I can't quite put my finger on it yet.  For starters, you generally do _not_ need to reseed on each call.  Once "per experiment" should do.

Comment: If you find that the accepted answer doesn't actually solve the problem, you can unaccept it, you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statistics intuition and use of a random number generator is not quite right.  If I take your code, add the missing include for `Rcpp.h` and the `namespace` directive and *simply comment out the reseeding* then the two histograms overlap as you expected.

[image]

Code below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector testRandomShuffle(IntegerVector x, int rd) { // rd is the seed
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end()); // copy
  //std::srand(rd); // seeding
  std::random_shuffle(&y[0], &*y.end());
  return y;
}


/***R
#v = runif(1000000)
v = runif(10000)
vSorted = sort(v)
sqc = 1L : length(v) # indexes
rd = sample.int(length(v), 100) # random seeds


# Compute correlation matrices
corMatForUnsorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  v[testRandomShuffle(sqc, x)])))
corMatForSorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  vSorted[testRandomShuffle(sqc, x)])))


# plot histograms
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) 
hist(corMatForUnsorted[abs(corMatForUnsorted) < 1], breaks = 200, xlab = 
  "Correlation for unsorted")
hist(corMatForSorted[abs(corMatForSorted) < 1], breaks = 200, xlab = 
  "Correlation for sorted")
*/
```

I also lowered `N` by two orders of magnitude. Good enough.

*Edit:* And for completeness, a pure Rcpp version using only one RNG which work whereever Rcpp works, including Windows with `g++-4.9.3`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector testRandomShuffle(IntegerVector x, int rd) { // rd is the seed
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end()); // copy
  std::random_shuffle(&y[0], &*y.end());
  return y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector testRandomSample(IntegerVector x) { // rd is the seed
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end()); // copy
  return sample(y, y.size());
}

/***R
set.seed(123)  # now we're reproducible
v <- runif(10000)
vSorted <- sort(v)
sqc <- 1L : length(v) # indexes
rd <- sample.int(length(v), 100) # random seeds

# Compute correlation matrices
corMatForUnsorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  v[testRandomSample(sqc)])))
corMatForSorted = cor(as.data.frame(lapply(rd, function(x) 
  vSorted[testRandomSample(sqc)])))

# plot histograms
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) 
hist(corMatForUnsorted[abs(corMatForUnsorted) < 1], breaks = 200, 
     xlab = "Correlation for unsorted", main="Unsorted")
hist(corMatForSorted[abs(corMatForSorted) < 1], breaks = 200, 
     xlab = "Correlation for sorted", main="Sorted")
*/
```

It still contains the unused older variant.  The result plot is now

[image]

And for completeness, in a benchmark the `sample()` routine from Rcpp is faster too:

```
R> library(rbenchmark)
R> benchmark(testRandomShuffle(x, 1), testRandomSample(x))[,1:4]
                     test replications elapsed relative
2     testRandomSample(x)          100   1.402    1.000
1 testRandomShuffle(x, 1)          100   1.868    1.332
R>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Dirk. I actually went without reseeding before posting, and the results were exactly the same, highly correlated. Just now I ran your code again, the correlations are still near 1. I noticed you use Linux? Also maybe in C++11 environment? I am using Windows with Rtools 3.4. I'll run the code on another Windows machine and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu 17.10, R 3.4.4, g++-7. On Windows you have an older compiler g++ 4.9.3 -- yet another reason to do that part with Rcpp rather than via an older copy of the C++ libraries...

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I just tested on another Windows machine with Rtools 3.5 which still uses g++ 4.9.3... It looks like the problem does lie in the outdated C++ library. A side question, I gave up the `sample()` in Rcpp because of multithreading. Currently that usage is still limited in single threading right?

Comment: Please.  Until you show profiling evidence you making moles into mountains.  The C++ standard library is parallel either.   In essence you're saying "I don't care that it is wrong as my gut tells me it may be faster" -- that is not really a tenable position, is it?

Comment: @user2961927 Try the second variant in the edited answer. Rcpp only.  Should work on Windows too.

Comment: surprisingly, I just tried your first block of code in this post, and my result turns out exactly the same as yours (with sample size 10000), and I am still using g++ 4.9.3! And I found once I increase the sample size to 1000000, high correlations show up. Would this still be the case on your side? I am sensing this has something to do with high / low discrepancy of the random sequences...

Comment: Not for me over here. It is well behaved for me if at two more orders of magnitude for `N`, and switch the routines -- in all cases histograms are cented around zero.

Answer (score 12):

[`std::random_shuffle(begin, end)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) often uses [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand), which is known to be a bad random number generator. From cppreference:

> `rand()` is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs. It is recommended to use C++11's random number generation facilities to replace `rand()`.

Use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead.

```
// Note the lack of `int rd`. `std::random_device` is better for
// seeding purposes, but it is non-deterministic.
IntegerVector testShuffle(IntegerVector x)
{
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end()); // copy

  // std::mt19937 is a rather heavy type. As such, it's often recommended
  // to make it a static variable. If you will be calling this function
  // from multiple threads, you'd want to make it `thread_local` instead
  // of `static` (or otherwise avoid the data race on `engine`).
  static std::mt19937 engine = [] {
    // Using the Immediately Invoked Lambda Expression (IILE) idiom to
    // initialize the static variable.

    // Seed the RNG.
    std::random_device rd;

    // Note that there are better ways to seed the mersenne twister.
    // This way is flawed, as it can't possibly initialize all of the
    // mersenne twister's state, but it's the simplest way for
    // demonstration purposes
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    return engine;
  }();

  // You should be able to just use y.begin(), y.end()
  std::shuffle(y.begin(), y.end(), engine);
  return y;
}
```

If you want to have a deterministic seed, note that a single `int` is not enough information to fully seed a `std::mt19937`, but you could use it anyway:

```
IntegerVector testShuffle(IntegerVector x, int seed)
{
  IntegerVector y(x.begin(), x.end());

  static std::mt19937 engine;

  // Not thread-friendly, but simple.
  // Also, note that you'll get bad results if you seed a mersenne twister
  // (or a lot of RNGs) with 0, so avoid that
  engine.seed(seed);

  std::shuffle(y.begin(), y.end(), engine);
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, upvoted! Also note that in Rcpp-land we have `sample()` in RcppArmadillo (older) and also in Rcpp.  Those will use R's RNGs.

Comment: Good answer; if the code might be multithreaded, use `thread_local` instead of `static`.